# Socket.io fails to connect, no error message "invalid packet format"

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

After update from Node v12 to v18 I'm struggling to get my Socket.io js app to connect to the server on localhost. There are no errors messages on either the client or server side, but the connection fails and is continually retried.

In the Network tab of my brower's dev tools I see a constant stream to HTTP 101 connections like this: `ws://localhost:6000/socket/?EIO=4&transport=websocket`

After [enabling debugging](https://socket.io/docs/v4/logging-and-debugging/) I see the following in the server logs:

```
  engine handshaking client "P3I-QeVPo7HbvWGUAAE2" +1s
  engine:transport readyState updated from undefined to open (websocket) +1s
  engine:socket readyState updated from undefined to opening +1s
  engine:socket readyState updated from opening to open +1ms
  engine:socket sending packet "open" ({"sid":"P3I-QeVPo7HbvWGUAAE2","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000,"maxPayload":100000000}) +0ms
  engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +1ms
  engine:ws writing "0{"sid":"P3I-QeVPo7HbvWGUAAE2","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000,"maxPayload":100000000}" +1s
  engine:transport setting request +5ms
  socket.io:server incoming connection with id P3I-QeVPo7HbvWGUAAE2 +1s
  engine:ws received "40" +5ms
  engine:socket received packet message +7ms
  socket.io-parser decoded 0 as {"type":0,"nsp":"/"} +1s
  socket.io:client connecting to namespace / +1s
  socket.io:namespace adding socket to nsp / +1s
  socket.io:client invalid packet format +2ms
  engine:socket readyState updated from open to closing +4ms
  engine:transport readyState updated from open to closing (websocket) +9ms
  engine:ws closing +6ms
  engine:socket readyState updated from closing to closed +2ms
  socket.io:client client close with reason forced close +4ms
  engine:transport readyState updated from closing to closed (websocket) +5ms
```

The heart of the issue seems to be: `socket.io:client invalid packet format +2ms`. However, I can't understand what would be the cause of that. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps mismatched versions of socket.io on client and server?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I considered that as well, but I update both the client and the server to the latest 4.5.0, and the error hasn't changed. :(

Comment: That's an odd one.  I guess I'd uninstall both client and server versions of socket.io and then install from scratch in case some older component is stuck in the installation.  If that still doesn't work, then try to code a new simple app that just has the bare basics of a socket.io connection in it and see if that works.

Comment: And, we might have more ideas if you show relevant client and server code.

Comment: Good idea. I tried deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling/rebuilding everything. No joy. I'll try to build something minimal to reproduce it and post code once I do.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who ends up here after hours of pulling their hair out like I was, I finally figured out that in my case the problem was with the `auth` option. I had changed it from an object to a function without realizing that the function was providing the token directly, just changing the callback invocation from `callback( auth.token )` to `callback( { token : auth.token } )` allowed it to start working.

Without debugging enabled there was no information at all being presented about what was happening, other than reconnecting over and over again. Even when I enabled debugging (with `DEBUG='socket*'`) the only information I was getting was "invalid packet format". I ended up modifying the socket.io code where that invalid packet format message was thrown to also log the thing it had tried to turn into a packet and it was logging auth tokens which led me to finally figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem turned out to be self-inflicted.

I use [socket.io-expression-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-express-session) to share session data between Express and Socket.io. A while back I had changed from using a simple function to handle the session middleware to a middleware chain array, but I forgot about it when I updated everything. Express can handle the array without issue, but the Socket.io middleware expected a function and broke.

I still don't know why I didn't get an error saying "hey, you're trying to call an array as a function," but once I reverted back to a function, all was well.

Thanks to @jfriend00 for helping me troubleshoot this.